# Pandas data frame sum of column and collecting the results

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
p1 = {'name': 'willy', 'age': 11, 'interest': "Lego"}
p2 = {'name': 'willy', 'age': 11, 'interest': "games"}
p3 = {'name': 'zoe', 'age': 9, 'interest': "cars"}
df = pd.DataFrame([p1, p2, p3])
df

    age interest    name
0   11  Lego        willy
1   11  games       willy
2   9   cars        zoe
```

I want to know the sum of interests of each person and let each person only show once in the list. I do the following:

```
Interests = df[['age', 'name', 'interest']].groupby(['age' , 'name']).count()
Interests.reset_index(inplace=True)
Interests.sort('interest', ascending=False, inplace=True)
Interests

    age name    interest
1   11  willy   2
0   9   zoe     1
```

This works but I have the feeling that I'm doing it wrong. Now I'm using the column 'interest' to display my sum values which is okay but like I said I expect there to be a nicer way to do this.

I saw many questions about counting/sum in Pandas but for me the part where I leave out the 'duplicates' is key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use size (the length of each group), rather than count, the non-NaN enties in each column of the group.

```
In [11]: df[['age', 'name', 'interest']].groupby(['age' , 'name']).size()
Out[11]:
age  name
9    zoe      1
11   willy    2
dtype: int64

In [12]: df[['age', 'name', 'interest']].groupby(['age' , 'name']).size().reset_index(name='count')
Out[12]:
   age   name  count
0    9    zoe      1
1   11  willy      2
```

Comment: This looks elegant. Could you explain what happens at [12] with .reset_index(name='count'). I understand that it creates the 'count' column but what does it have to do with resetting the index? Isn't the 0 and 1 in the unnamed column the index? **edit** Can you expand on why size() would be better then count() here?

Comment: before reset_index it's a Series and the index is a MultiIndex (of age and name). reset_index makes these into columns and name gives the column from the Series a name (by default it's 0). See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html

Comment: Thank you, I still need to get used to the idea that performing an operation on an object can completely change the object type. I guess when using Pandas it is something you should get used to fast :)

Comment: the object doesn't change, this is returned by the method (unless you use "inplace", but that's not recommended IMO)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   age interest   name
0   11     Lego  willy
1   11    games  willy
2    9     cars    zoe

In [3]: for name,group in df.groupby('name'):
   ...:     print name
   ...:     print group.interest.count()
   ...:     
willy
2
zoe
1
```