# Pandas data frame sum of column and combing with other data

Tags: python, pandas, twitter

This is a continuation on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33504457/pandas-data-frame-sum-of-column-and-collecting-the-results) I asked before and got a suitable answer for at the time. Now however my problem is different and the given answers no longer (completely) applies.

I have a big collection of Twitter messages and I want to do some statistical analysis on it. Part of the data frame looks as follows:

```
user.id      user.screen_name      user.followers_count      text
Jim          JimTHEbest            14                        blahbla
Jim          JIMisCOOL             15                        blebla
Sarah        Sarah123              33                        blaat
Sarah        Sarah123              33                        bla
Peter        PeterOnline           9                         blabla
```

**user.id** never changes and is a identifier of a Twitter account.

**user.screen_name** Name given to twitter account, can change over time.

**user.followers_count** How many followers account has, can change over time.

**text** twitter message, each row represents 1 twitter message and its meta data.

What i would like to do is count the frequency of tweets by each twitter user in my data frame and combine it with the data that I already have. So that I get something like this:

```
user.id      user.screen_name      user.followers_count      count
Jim          JIMisCOOL             15                        2
Sarah        Sarah123              33                        2
Peter        PeterOnline           9                         1
```

A data frame with 1 row for each twitter user in my data set that shows their tweet count and the last screen_name and followers_count.

What I think I should do is first do the 'count' operation and then pd.merge that outcome with a part of my original data frame. Trying merge with help of the pandas documentation didn't get me very far, mostly endlessly repeating rows of duplicate data.. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The count part I do as follows:

```
df[['name', 'text']].groupby(['name']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Comment: if you want one row for each 'user.id' unique value in your final data, which row you want to keep if the user have more than one row?

Comment: Each row is a Tweet, which were collected over time. So for these metrics I would want the latest entry in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it myself, but I'm also going to look into the other answers, they are probably different for a reason :).

```
df2 = df[['user.id', 'text']].groupby(['user.id']).size().reset_index(name='count')
df = df.set_index('user.id')
df2 = df2.set_index('user.id')
frames =  [df2, df]
result = pd.concat(frames, axis=1, join_axes=[df.index])
result = result.reset_index()
result = result.drop_duplicates(['user.id'], keep='last')
result = result[['user.id', 'user.screen_name', 'user.followers_count', 'count']]
result

    user.id user.screen_name    user.followers_count    count
1   Jim     JIMisCOOL           15                      2
3   Sarah   Sarah123            33                      2
4   Peter   PeterOnline         9                       1
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see the results using `%%timeit` on your larger dataset.

Answer (score 1):

```
# df being the original dataframe, taking the last row of each unique user.id and ignoring the 'text' column
output_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='user.id', take_last=True)[['user.id', 'user.screen_name', 'user.followers_count']]
# adding the 'count' column
output_df['count'] = df['user.id'].apply(lambda x: len(df[df['user.id'] == x]))
output_df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
print output_df
>>   user.id user.screen_name  user.followers_count  count
   0     Jim        JIMisCOOL                    15      2
   1   Sarah         Sarah123                    33      2
   2   Peter      PeterOnline                     9      1
```

Answer (score 1):

You group on `user.id`, and then use `agg` to apply a custom aggregation function to each column.  In this case, we use a `lambda` expression and then use `iloc` to take the last member of each group.  We then use `count` on the text column.

```
result = df.groupby('user.id').agg({'user.screen_name': lambda group: group.iloc[-1], 
                                    'user.followers_count': lambda group: group.iloc[-1], 
                                    'text': 'count'})
result.rename(columns={'text': 'count'}, inplace=True)

>>> result[['user.screen_name', 'user.followers_count', 'count']]
        user.screen_name  user.followers_count  count
user.id                                              
Jim            JIMisCOOL                    15      2
Peter        PeterOnline                     9      1
Sarah           Sarah123                    33      2
```